# Using PostgreSQL 9.0 and PostGIS 1.5 on Debian Squeeze

Tags: postgresql, debian-squeeze, postgis

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.0 (`postgresql`) and PostGIS 1.5 (`postgis`) from Debian Backports on my freshly installed Squeeze (stable).

However, when trying to create a PostGIS-enabled database, I noticed that I’m missing the “enabler script” `postgis.sql`. According to the manual, it should be in `[prefix]/share/contrib`, but `/usr/share/postgresql/9.0/contrib`doesn’t exist until I install `postgresql-contrib-9.0` as well, but the file isn’t included there as well.

Now apparently the file might come with the `postgresql-x.x-postgis` packages, however, there’s no such package for 9.0 yet (or I’m too stupid to find it).

So, Debian and PostGIS gods, what shall I do? Just get the .sql file from the PostGIS source? Install the `postgresql-8.4-postgis` package (which pulls PostgreSQL 8.4)? Something completely different?

(I need 8.3 or 9.0 because the OpenStreetMap installation guide I’m using says that 8.4 performs poorly with OSM, and I figured that instead of using 8.3 I might as well use the newer version. So, “you absolutely want to use 8.3 instead of 9.0” is a valid suggestion as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the currently broken blog [here](http://tech.xlab.si/2011/01/postgresql-9-0-postgis-and-friends-for-debian-squeeze/) ([Googlecache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:vKrg3CLGSKUJ:tech.xlab.si/2011/01/postgresql-9-0-postgis-and-friends-for-debian-squeeze/%20postgis%20squeeze)).  There is a repository of postgres9/postgis1.5.2/etc binaries for 64-bit architectures at

```
deb http://www.gmajna.net/svojat/jaka/apt-pgsql/ squeeze main contrib non-free
```

Otherwise, you'll probably need to compile and install postgis from source against 9.0 yourself, which will need the headers from the [`postgresql-server-dev-9.0`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/postgresql-server-dev-9.0) package.

Comment: Since I don’t want to use unofficial repositories, I’ve installed PostGIS from source. Seems to work. Thank you very much.